# Initiating key-binds in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to mute and un-mute my microphone inside of a python script as part of an Arduino project and I can't find any simple way to do that. so my current idea is to bind mute on certain programs to something like shift+delete and then calling that from a python script. I have already tried the following using pywin32.

```
import win32api
win32api.keybd_event(0x10,0,0, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(0x2E,0,0, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(0x2E,0,0x0002, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(0x10,0,0x0002, 0)
```

this presses the buttons (tested in a text editor) but does not call the key-bind.

*I'm currently using python 3.6*

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use pyAutoGui to press the keys. 
Here is the documentation for pyAutoGui:
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pyautogui/latest/pyautogui.pdf

Comment: This worked thanks mate! although i had to change the hotkey to something like' ctrl+m'.